# Get Azure VM related details using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I  am trying to use  Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent and related set of packages,

I need following details about ALL azure VM in my subscription:

Who created VM, Region of VM,    VmSize, Current Status of VM ( Like Stopped/ Running/ Deallocated etc),

I also need
History of VM in terms of duration this VM was up and running for last x months/ weeks.

Is this possible using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent packages?

Comment: Could you please tell me what do you mean `History of VM in terms of duration this VM was up and running for last x months/ weeks`? Is that you want to know the vm running time?

Comment: history means VM stop and VM start time for last x days/ months

Comment: According to my understanding, you want to know when to start or shut down the VM in last x days or months. Right?

Comment: yes when was VM started and stopped in past date/ time

Comment: If so, you can get these information in activity log : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/activity-log-view. But, please note that we just can get last 90 days log.

Comment: If you want to use Azure SDK to get activity log. You can use the package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Fluent. For more details, please refer to https://github.com/Azure-Samples/monitor-dotnet-query-metrics-activitylogs/blob/master/Program.cs#L110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the VM starting and stopping time, we can get it from Azure activity log. Regarding how to retrieve the activity log, we can use Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Fluent package.

For example

1. create a service principal and assign Azure RABC role to the sp(I use Azure CLI)

```
az login
#it will create a service principal and assign contributor role to the sp
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "jonsp2"
```

[image]

2. Install package

```
// for more details about the package, please refer to https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent -Version 1.34.0
```

3. Code

```
 AzureCredentials credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(
                       clientId, // the sp appId
                       clientSecret, // the sp password
                       tenantId, // the sp tenant  
                        AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
            var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure.Configure()
                                                      .Authenticate(credentials)
                                                      .WithSubscription(subscriptionId);

            var vms = await azure.VirtualMachines.ListAsync();
            foreach (var vm in vms)
            {
                var staus = vm.PowerState.Value; // vm power state
                var region = vm.RegionName; // vm region
                var size = vm.Size.Value; // vm size
                var logs = await azure.ActivityLogs.DefineQuery()
                              .StartingFrom(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
                              .EndsBefore(DateTime.Now)
                              .WithAllPropertiesInResponse()
                              .FilterByResource("/subscriptions/e5b0fcfa-e859-43f3-8d84-5e5fe29f4c68/resourceGroups/jimtest/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/testvm")
                              .ExecuteAsync();
                List<DateTime?> stopTime = new List<DateTime?>();
                List<DateTime?> startTime = new List<DateTime?>();
                foreach (var log in logs)
                {
                    // get stop time
                    if ((log.OperationName.LocalizedValue == "Deallocate Virtual Machine") & (log.Status.LocalizedValue == "Succeeded"))
                    {

                        stopTime.Add(log.EventTimestamp);
                    }
                    // get start tim
                    if ((log.OperationName.LocalizedValue == "Strat Virtual Machine") & (log.Status.LocalizedValue == "Succeeded"))
                    {

                        startTime.Add(log.EventTimestamp);
                    }



                }
            }
```